# Simple question about pseudorandom generator

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cr.crypto-security, pseudorandomness, pseudorandom-generators

I am stuck on the following question related to pseudorandom generator and any help would be appreciated.

> Let $G:\{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}^{k+1}$ be a pseudorandom generator. Define $G':\{0,1\}^{2k}  \to \{0,1\}^{2k+2}$ by $G'(x_1x_2)=G(x_1)G(x_2)$ where $x_1, x_2 \in \{0,1\}^k$.
>
> Prove that $G'$ is not a pseudorandom generator in general.

I don't think it is necessary (and feasible) to find a counter-example $G'$ since it requires us to find a pseudorandom generator $G$, (which means we will have proved the existence of pseudorandom if we can find such $G$) so normally how can we tackle this kind of problem?

Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: Is there any relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ that can be identified at the output?

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: @Yuval: By definition, $G'$ is pseudorandom if for large-enough, **randomly selected** $x_1x_2 \in \{0,1\}^{2k}$, the output of $G'$ on $x_1x_2$ is computationally indistinguishable from the uniform distribution. Since the seed is randomly selected, it is unstructured, meaning you can't assume any relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @Yuval (cont'd): On the other hand, even for the random selection of the seed, there might be some structuredness in the output which leads to distinguishing it from uniform distribution. For instance, a $1 / 2^k$ fraction of inputs have $x_1=x_2$, leading to $G(x_1)=G(x_2)$ (this is not enough per se, since this fraction is negligible).

Comment: If the adversary is given the preimage of G' then could he not, using G' as a blackbox distinguish G' from a uniform distribution with high probability by feeding the black box the preimage with the last half of the bits swapped with the first half?

Comment: @Ross: I'm afraid the definition of pseudorandom generators does not allow that. As I said in previous comments, the definition is based on distinguishing two distribution ensembles: $\{G(U_n)\}_n$ and $\{G(U_{\ell(n)})\}_n$, where $U_m$ is a uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^m$, and $\ell$ is the generators stretch function. The distinguisher can be non-uniform, but it is not given anything besides a member of either ensemble.

Comment: @Suki, if there are no PRNGs then there is no $G$ so the construction for $G'$ works trivially. The way to find a counterexample is to find one assuming the minimal assumption, i.e. assume that there exists a PRNG and then try to build one using it such that the construction for $G'$ does not work. (I also think that this is a homework *level* question even if it is not a homework).

Comment: ps: It seems to me that this construction works (i.e. is secure) since breaking it means breaking $G$ with multiple sampling, and that is equivalent to breaking $G$ (using single sampling). You can find the argument in Crypto textbooks, "PRNG secure against multiple sampling". So if there is not a relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ this is secure (and I guess this was the reason for Yuval's comment).

Comment: @Sadeq The way I tried to approach this problem is similar to the work in section 4.3 of Alon Rosen's "SWIFFT: A modest Proposal for FFT Hashing." Specifically, Rosen says "given (adaptive) oracle access to a function f, no adversary can efficiently distinguish between the case where (1) f is chosen at random from the given family, and (2) every output of f is uniformly random and independent of all other outputs." I don't question that you know what you're talking about. Can you help me figure out what _I'm_ talking about?

Comment: @Ross: I didn't mean that you're questioning me. I just wanted to point out the model used for defining pseudorandom generators. Regarding @Alon Rosen's paper, I think it is modeling a keyed family of hash functions. The security of such family is defined by first randomly choosing a member, and then measuring the security (say, collision resistance). The model *you* defined, in which adversary has access to the seed, is not sound because no PRG can resist such attack (neither $G$ nor $G'$). After all, a PRG is a deterministic algorithm acting on a random seed.

Comment: @Sadeq: Thank you for being patient. I was trying to show that, with oracle access to G' there is a way to distinguish it from a random oracle; namely pick a random a,b then run G'(ab) and G'(ba) and check that their outputs correspond to some xy and yx (which is unlikely to hold for a random oracle). I understand now that this model is not useful for defining PRNGs since a TM could always implement the PRG itself and compare input-output pairs between its 'personal' implementation and the oracle to distinguish it from the random oracle. Oops. :-[

Comment: @Ross: You're most welcome! One more thing: PRGs are not comparable to random oracles (ROs). The closest construct in cryptography to ROs are **pseudorandom functions** (PRFs), as described in [[GGM86](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=6503)]. Their PRFs are based on PRGs. Note that, in contrast to ROs, PRFs are keyed.

Comment: @Sadeq: I'm both ashamed and excited at the amount I have left to learn. Thanks again!

Comment: As others have shown, this is in fact valid but less efficient than the traditional construction. See: https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs127/fall13/lec11.pdf

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean a cryptographic PRG.

Let's assume on the contrary that the $G'$ is not secure. So let $A$ be a probabilistic Turing machine that distinguishes the output of $G'$ from uniformly random bits.

Let $x_1,x_2$ be $k$ bit random strings, and let $z_1,z_2$ be $k+1$ bit random strings.

We have that $A$ distinguishes the distribution of strings $D_0 : G(x_1)G(x_2)$ and 
$D_2: z_1z_2$.

Consider now the *hybrid* distribution of strings given by $D_1: G(x_1)z_2$.

By the triangle inequality $A$ also distinguishes between either $D_0$ and $D_1$ or between $D_1$ and $D_2$.

Assume without loss of generality that  $A$ distinguishes between $D_0$ and $D_1$.
Then we can break $G$ as follows. On input $y$, pick uniformly random $k$ bit string $x_1$ and give the string $G(x_1)y$ to $A$.

Comment: Well done, Kristoffer!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I've been thinking about this construction for quite some time, and I didn't came up with a counterexample to its security.</strike> As [Kristoffer showed](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4787/4795#4795), your construct is secure.
However, I wanted to point out that your construction is outperformed by the traditional one (in almost all cases), whereas you claimed:

> I wonder whether there is any "trivial" construction that is better than the "extra-bit" construction, and therefore I came across the "construction" in my question.

Let me elaborate. A pseudorandom generator is a function $G \colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^{\ell(n)}$, where $\ell(\cdot)$ is a *stretch function*; that is, $\ell(n) > n$ for all $n$. The function $G$ has to satisfy some security requirements, which I'm neglecting for the moment. (My comments above mention these requirements.)

Now assume that we have a seed $s$ of size $n$. Applying $G(G(s))$, we stretch this seed to a pseudorandom bit sequence of size $\ell(\ell(n))$, while applying your construct, one gets an output of size $\ell(n/2) + \ell(n/2)$.<strike>, and we don't even know that this output is pseudorandom.</strike>

**Two examples:**

1) For you case, $\ell(n) = n + 1$:

- The traditional construction output is $(n+1)+1 = n+2$ bits;
- Your construction output is $(n/2+1)+(n/2+1) = n+2$ bits;

So the performance are the same.

2) On the other hand, for $\ell(n) = 3n$

- The traditional construction output is $3(3n) = 9n$ bits;
- Your construction output is $(3n/2)+(3n/2) = 3n$ bits;

And your construction is outperformed.

Answer (score 0):

@Jukka: This is not a homework problem. Recently I have read about pseudorandom generator in a book, and it talks about increasing the expansion factor of a pseudorandom generator.

Given a pseudorandom generator $G:\{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}^{k+1}$, we can construct a pseudorandom generator $G_d:\{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}^{k+d}$ by iteratively applying $G$ on the seed to get an extra bit in each iteration.

I wonder whether there is any "trivial" construction that is better than the "extra-bit" construction, and therefore I came across the "construction" in my question.

I believe that the "construction" in the question does not give a pseudorandom generator in general, so I attempt to prove that by myself, but then I realise that the "normal" approach of finding a counterexample does not work in this case. I have no idea how to tackle this problem, so I would like to get some help on solving this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: this should really be a comment.

Comment: I agree with Suresh. I tired unsuccessfully to convert it into a comment but it is too long. It might be better to incorporate this in the question as the motivation.